# 500 Internal Server Error instead of 404 in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When I try to find out the value that is not there in the database I get 500 Internal Server Error. I have already provided logic to throw `ResourceNotFoundException` error, but, it's not working for some reason. What do I need to do to get `404 ResourceNotFoundException` instead of `500 Internal Server Error`.
Here's my code:

```
@PostMapping("/start/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> startEvent(@PathVariable() Long id) {
        Event event = this.eventRepository.findById(id).get();

        if (event == null) {
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Event with id " + id + " not found.");
        }

        event.setStarted(true);
        this.eventRepository.save(event);

        return ResponseEntity.ok("Event " + event.getName() + " has started");
    }
```

I guess eventRepository.findById(id)   //id = 200 returns 500 response as record with id 200 does not exist in the database. What should I do to get   ResourceNotFoundException?

Comment: You sure you're not getting an exception after calling `get` on the return value of `findById`?

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but is there a reason why you're using `@PostMapping` instead of `@GetMapping`?

Comment: @TwiN2 yes, I am storing data in the database using this.eventRepository.save(event);

Comment: Why are you throwing an exception if event is null?  Why wouldn't you react to that and set ResponseEntity to 404?  Who do you expect to handle that exception?  Your method ought to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`eventRepository.findById` returns `Optional` (in Spring Data JPA 2.0.6, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.0.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.core-concepts)

`Optional.get` on empty optional causes `NoSuchElementException` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#get--). Your `if (event == null)`  comes too late.
Checking stactrace, you should see that exception comes from line with  `this.eventRepository.findById` and actual exception is `NoSuchElementException`

To fix that you should change your code to

```
    Optional<Event> optionalEvent= this.eventRepository.findById(id);
    if (!optionalEvent.isPresent()) {
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Event with id " + id + " not found.");
    }
 Event event=optionalEvent.get();
 //the rest of your logic
```

You may also write your code in more functional way

```
Event event = this.eventRepository
.findById(id)
.orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Event with id " + id + " not found."))
```

**Summary**

Do not call `get()` on `Optional` without checking if it is present (using `isPresent()` method)

Answer (score 3):

`eventRepository.findById()` return an `Optional`
Therefore you have to test for existence before `get()`

```
Optional<Event> optEvent = eventRepository.findById();
if (!optEvent.isPresent()) {
 //throw exception here   
}
```